# Сложный редирект htaccess. Как реализовать без конфликта?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Как правильно составить редирект при таких условиях?

1. Главную страницу оставить без редиректа
2. Основные статьи (около 10-ти всего) редиректить на такие же статьи
   нового сайта с измененной структурой ссылок.
3. И самое главное - все остальные не столь значительные статьи просто редиректить на главную станицу нового сайта.

Как сделать так, что бы условия выполнялись правильно и не противоречили друг другу? Как задать такую последовательность?

Answer (score 1):

Это легче чем кажется.

Создаем в корне сайта файл .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^first-article/ http://new-site.com/new-article-address.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^second-article/ http://new-site.com/new-article2-address.html [R=301,L]

#и так далее перечисляем все важные статьи.

#далее строим общее правило для менее важных страниц

#в условии сказано: если НЕ главная страница, то редирект для всех страниц на новый сайт
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^$)
RewriteRule .* http://new-site.com/ [R=301,L]
```

В последней строчке выражение .* - есть регулярное выражение которое означает любой адрес после имени сайта.

Если у вас используется формирование страницы через GET параметры, например /index.php?article_id=19 то нужно испольщовать другой формат.

```
RewriteEngine On

#в данном случае используется связка условие-правило. 
#При  чем можно сделать несколько условий для одного правила. 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article_id=19
RewriteRule .* http://new-site.com/article_19/ [R=301,L]
```

Надеюсь я смог донести мысль :)